# Relative image map

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, position

So hello everyone.
I was trying to put an image on a webpage and make part of it clickable.
I've found [this](https://www.image-map.net/) site and it was pretty handy. Then I added a little jquery and made those parts a button, etc. 
But the problem is that I want this image to display correctly in different sizes and ratios of monitors.
This site's coordinates were absolute, and you know that this is not a good thing for making a page responsive.
Is there any way to make those coordinates relative somehow? (I believe this is not most likely the solution)
Or is there any other approach to make part of an image clickable and keep the page with the image responsive?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You may use mediaqueries, transform and  margin to overcome the scale() : https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/AJHmt coordonates will be kept without recalculation. (demo shows the buttons via CSS for the fun of it, do not use it, it is not crossbrowser) the rescaling might be what you look for.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you for you're helpful comment! I see that those areas are still in absolute values and the media queries aren't changing anything in them. Does the scale() method change those coordinate as well?

Comment: no, it only rescale it (everything) , but the initial room used, never chage if your map is a thousand pixel wide, it will remain the same even scaled down to 0. ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus So what I've understood is that I can scale the image and map tags of my page, and the result would be the same image and map, but the areas are still at the same positions of the image. Is that correct? sorry about my dumb questions, I consider myself a noob in frontend :)

Comment: i guess this is it. just play around with the codepen to find out ;)

Comment: when you scale a parent, whatever is inside is rescaled as well. proportions remains the same, it just becomes bigger or smaller :) .

Comment: Maybe the best is that you add your tries to your question, so we can help from your code if you have a few issues

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you so much. The project that I'm working on has some rules about their resources not being leaked into the public. I couldn't actually share the code here, I guess. And my bigger question was how to make part of an image a button that I've mentioned the method I have found. Thank you again so much, I think you should post an answer, because my problem seems to be solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple example instead the pen i linked earlier,  using scale(), margin and mediaqueries to reset their values.

Since transform has no effect on the original size and space used by the the transformed element, if you rescale it, the room it uses does not. margin can go over it, increase margin around it while scaling up to push things away, and decrease margin with negative value while scaling down to pull things around it.

```css
img {
  border: solid;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width:250px) {
  img {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    margin: -75px -125px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  img {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    margin: -30px -50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
  img {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin: 75px 125px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  img {
    transform: scale(2);
    margin: 150px -250px;
  }
}

map {/* for the demo, wrap it and use a div to avoid funny behaviors */
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<map name="map_example">
  <area shape="rect" coords="98,60,375,220" href="#sunny" alt="Sun">
  <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R27c41ba1d38afc9894a202c4d1dfdf7f?rik=941mYlhkC070wQ&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.thesmartbaby.com%2f_borders%2fgreenrectangle.jpg&ehk=YSaA6ZnTbw02zKN1w%2b9P5cze61mc4XAJ4YpPeX7inO0%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw"    alt="image map example" width='500' height='300' usemap="#map_example">  
</map>
```

If you need to add visible element over your image , you can use grid (or absolute positionning) and map becomes unnecessary (areas are not meant to be shown by browsers) . The method is the same reset margin while rescaling.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

a,
img {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: solid;
}

a {
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 60px 0 0 97px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(100, 200, 50, 0.5), gray, rgba(255, 125, 0, 05));
  /*chrome*/ position:relative;
}

a:hover {
  background: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:250px) {
  div {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    margin: -75px -125px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
  div {
    transform: scale(0.8);
    margin: -30px -50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
  div {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin: 75px 125px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  div {
    transform: scale(2);
    margin: 150px 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R27c41ba1d38afc9894a202c4d1dfdf7f?rik=941mYlhkC070wQ&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.thesmartbaby.com%2f_borders%2fgreenrectangle.jpg&ehk=YSaA6ZnTbw02zKN1w%2b9P5cze61mc4XAJ4YpPeX7inO0%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw" alt="image map example"
    width='500' height='300' usemap >
  <a href="#sunny"> green rectangle</a>
</div>
```

You can remove the usemap attribute. I left here for the image and added a border that becomes blue like a link. Looks like it is expected that this image is a link to elsewhere for firefox :).